# Mac OS X automatic backup: launchd + s3cmd = «Error: Can't find a config file»

Tags: macos, backup, launchd, amazon-s3

I want to setup automatic backup on schedule from my mac to amazone s3. I'm using for this purpose launchd + s3cmd.

s3cmd is working fine in terminal.app. But launchd can't run s3cmd. I see in system.log errors like:

```
Mar  5 12:48:17 kinds-MacBook com.kind.s3cmd[13060]: ERROR: Can't find a config file. Please use --config option.
Mar  5 12:48:17 kinds-MacBook com.apple.launchd[1] (com.kind.s3cmd[13060]): Exited with exit code: 1
```

Looks like launchd has different from Bash environment.

How can I use s3cmd with launchd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTFM as usual:

s3sync needs to know several interesting values to work right.  It looks for 
them in the following environment variables -or- a s3config.yml file.
In the yml case, the names need to be lowercase (see example file).
Furthermore, the yml is searched for in the following locations, in order:

$S3CONF/s3config.yml
   $HOME/.s3conf/s3config.yml
   /etc/s3conf/s3config.yml

http://s3.amazonaws.com/ServEdge_pub/s3sync/README.txt